# forbidden on the home page and work on only one page with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

forbidden on the home page and work on only one page with htaccess

how to set the domain for one page and forbidden on the home page with htaccess.

i use:

```
apache 2.4
php 7
```

I have two domain for one website.

```
domainA.com
domainB.com
```

I need *domainB.com* **forbidden error** on Home page but work on this link:

this link has two parameter

```
http://domainB.com/api/cto?ca=$1&ru=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below rule if you want forbidden error on root of domainB.com,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainB.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: now my root on this domain is Forbidden but other link dont work , like this http://domainB.com/api/cto?ca=$1&ru=$2 , now is not found.